# Tiny Death Star multiple instances

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I keep getting prompted when starting the app to choose my Death Star. Apparently I have two separate Death Stars being built. One local and one online. However, I don't want two separate Death Stars. This happened after the latest patch (1.2.2) has anyone else had this happen? Am I just missing something? Is there a way to merge the two so that the one will continue on being the only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two Death Stars are an online copy and your local version.  I don't know why they keep asking which one you wish to work on.  My impression is that the online version is meant as a backup copy and possibly a Facebook tie-in.  If you click on the menu and look in the center, there is now an option to save and log into Facebook.

As for myself, I always choose the local option.  I think that this may represent a newly implemented feature that isn't quite working properly.  (*i.e.* a bug)

My impression is that when you use the local option, it creates a backup copy in the online version.  I believe this because when I added new floors, the online version had the same number of floors.

Comment: This is my impression as well.  I always opt to open the local option.

Comment: I too had to choose. Can't remember which one I chose, only remember that I chose the one that's most recent.

Comment: I think that, as long as you only play on one device, the local option _should_ always be the most recent.  If you play with multiple devices, it could be either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it asks only when the two copies become out of sync. It's backed up an older version of your death star, and if you play with it on your device while out of Wi-Fi or data connection range, it won't be able to update the backup. And when you get back into range, as far as it knows, you might have played on some other device and updated the backup from there, in which case it needs to know which one to keep and which to discard. In general all it actually means is one more button to press occasionally, since I think the most recent one should always be the one you want for most users.

I'm just super happy that the backup option is there at all, so I could migrate to a device that didn't take three minutes to load my death star and still didn't show half the images!

Comment: This is correct.  I've been in a hotel with spotty wifi/cellular and I've noticed that I frequently get the prompt about the online version.